# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql' in M1 Macbook pro

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector, apple-m1

I have installed MySQL Server 8.0.27 through https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/, arm version ofcourse. I also installed MySQL WorkBench 8.0.27.

At the moment, I still can't access my SQL server through Terminal. Anyway, I then tried to access it through python jupyter notebook. Yesterday I could access and created several tables in SQL server. I could also see those tables through WorkBench now. But today, I run the same notebook again `import mysql.connector`, an error pops up again.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/r5/wq0wq8mx0d56rbrbs38jt94w0000gn/T/ipykernel_47606/4131037277.py in <module>
----> 1 import mysql.connector

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

I have installed :

```
brew install mysql

pip install mysqlclient

pip install mysql-connector-python
```

But still can't solved the problem.

I am suspecting there may be something related to my zshrc. My zshrc is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v_JNC25VaUKpGXdScpPe5PWoKCus1ri6/view?usp=sharing).

My mysql path is `usr/local/mysql-8.0.27-macos11-arm64/bin`.

My python is 3.9.6, installed by mini conda.
I have pyenv 3.9.5.

When I start up my Visual Studio Code, it says `pyenv shell 3.9.5`, but when I do `python -V` it returns `Python 3.9.6`. When i use jupyter notebook, I always set my Kernel to 3.9.6.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I `pip uninstall mysql-connector-python`
then `pip install mysql-connector-python` solved my problem.

Do I have to keep my MySQL WorkBench on all the time?